# Magento 1.9.1 - CSS not loading during installation

Tags: css, magento, permissions, magento-1.9

I am trying to install Magento 1.9.1. But there is some problem in first step. Page not loading CSS. Perhaps the reason could be permission. But I tried after giving permission also and still no success.

[image]

Please refer the screenshot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to 2 things,

1. Permission Issue : cannot access the css files.
2. Incorrect base Url.

Try inspecting the links in the browser, and check if you can access the raw CSS files.